# Slider starts on second image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using an slider created by myself with the help of some people of stackoverflow community.

The problem I have is that slider starts from the second image, not the first.

[image]

I'm starting it with 0, so I don't know where is the problem, any ideas?

This is the script:

```
    function slider(sel, intr, i) {
        var _slider = this;
        this.ind = i;
        this.selector = sel;
        this.slide = [];
        this.slide_active = 0;
        this.amount;
        this.timer = null;
        this.selector.children('img').each(function (i) {
            _slider.slide[i] = $(this);
            $(this).hide();
        });

        //Display buttons and register events
        $(this.selector).hover(
        function () {
            $(this).append('<div id="previous-slider-' + i + '" class="previous-arrow arrow"></div>');
            $(this).append('<div id="next-slider-' + i + '" class="next-arrow arrow"></div>');
            $('#next-slider-' + i).click(function () {
                _slider.next();
            });
            $('#previous-slider-' + i).click(function () {
                _slider.previous();
            });
        },
        function () {
            //Remove buttons and events
            $('.arrow').remove();
        });

        this.run();
    }       
    slider.prototype.run = function () {
        this.next();
    }
    slider.prototype.next = function () {
        var _s = this;
        _s.show(1);/*
    */
    }
    slider.prototype.previous = function () {
        var _s = this;
        _s.show(-1);
    }
    slider.prototype.show = function (shift) {
        var _s = this;
        _s.slide[_s.slide_active].fadeOut(300, function () {
            _s.slide_active = (_s.slide_active + shift < 0) ? _s.slide.length - 1 : (_s.slide_active + shift) % _s.slide.length;
            _s.slide[_s.slide_active].fadeIn(300)
        });
    }

    var slides = [];
    $('.slider').each(function (i) {
        slides[i] = new slider($(this), i);
    });
```

This is the script of the thumbs:

```
    $('.box').each( function(n){
        $(this).attr("target","galeria" + n);
    });

    $('.slider_box').each( function(n){
        $(this).attr("id","galeria" + n);
    });

    $('.box').click( function() {
        var toLoad = $(this).attr("target");
        $('.modal_container').fadeIn();
        $('.slider_box#'+toLoad).fadeIn();
    });
```

Comment: Maybe I've overlooking it but can you show what code invokes the gallery to pull up?

Comment: Sorry, let me update it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cant use jsfille hereś the solution code

```
    function slider(sel, intr, i) {
        var _slider = this;
        this.ind = i;
        this.selector = sel;
        this.slide = [];
        this.slide_active = 0;
        this.amount;
        this.timer = null;
        this.selector.children('img').each(function (i) {
            _slider.slide[i] = $(this);
            $(this).hide();
        });

        //Display buttons and register events
        $(this.selector).hover(
        function () {
            $(this).append('<div id="previous-slider-' + i + '" class="previous-arrow arrow">Previous</div>');
            $(this).append('<div id="next-slider-' + i + '" class="next-arrow arrow">Next</div>');
            $('#next-slider-' + i).click(function () {
                _slider.next();
            });
            $('#previous-slider-' + i).click(function () {
                _slider.previous();
            });
        },
        function () {
            //Remove buttons and events
            $('.arrow').remove();
        });

        this.run();
    }
    slider.prototype.run = function () {
        var _s = this;
        _s.show(0);
       _s.timer = setInterval(function () {
        _s.next();
       },interval);
    }
    slider.prototype.next = function () {
        var _s = this;
        clearInterval(this.timer);
        _s.show(1);
        this.timer = setInterval(function () {
            _s.show(1);
        }, interval);
    }
    slider.prototype.previous = function () {
        var _s = this;
        clearInterval(this.timer);
        _s.show(-1);
        this.timer = setInterval(function () {
            _s.show(1);
        }, interval);
    }
    slider.prototype.show = function (shift) {
        var _s = this;
        _s.slide[_s.slide_active].fadeOut(300, function () {
            _s.slide_active = (_s.slide_active + shift < 0) ? _s.slide.length - 1 : (_s.slide_active + shift) % _s.slide.length;
            _s.slide[_s.slide_active].fadeIn(300);
        });
    }

    var slides = [];
    var interval = 3000
    $('.slider').each(function (i) {
        slides[i] = new slider($(this), interval, i);
    });slider.prototype.previous = function () {
        var _s = this;
        clearInterval(this.timer);
        _s.show(-1);
        this.timer = setInterval(function () {
            _s.show(1);
        }, interval);
    }
    slider.prototype.show = function (shift) {
        var _s = this;
        _s.slide[_s.slide_active].fadeOut(300, function () {
            _s.slide_active = (_s.slide_active + shift < 0) ? _s.slide.length - 1 : (_s.slide_active + shift) % _s.slide.length;
            _s.slide[_s.slide_active].fadeIn(300);
        });
    }

    var slides = [];
    var interval = 3000
    $('.slider').each(function (i) {
        slides[i] = new slider($(this), interval, i);
    });
```

Comment: everytime you hit 'next' with this it will only show the first image

Comment: you got me wrong, you just need to add to your run-function a timeout because you didnt set one  take a look  http://jsfiddle.net/vbRLU/25/

Comment: but your fiddle starts also on second image, doesn't it?

Comment: sorry, the fiddle should be updated now of course it works but yu need to set a timeout delay and you must show(0)

Comment: I tried with your code using an interval but now it starts on the third image. Did you test it?

Comment: dont know everytime i cklick on the link i see the your initial code, i updated my answer yo

Answer (score 0):

I haven't been able to test this but it's possible that your slider is immediately calling the `run` function

```
slider.prototype.run = function () {
    this.next();
}
```

If this is the case the next function takes the active slide (in this case `0`) and immediately shows the second one `1`.

Inside the function replace `this.next()` with `this.show()`.

Again just a guess since I can't step through it.

Comment: Thanks Jon, tried changing it to `this.show()` but then it hides all images. Here it's a fiddle of my slider that reproduces the same error, starts on the second image too.. http://jsfiddle.net/vbRLU/25/ In the website i'm working I removed the interval (which the fiddle has), but it doesn't change anything on the start of it so don't worry about it...

Comment: I'm stumped. I know it has something to do with running `this.run()` immediately when the function is called because that immediately invokes the `.next()` function